# PostgreSQL query and data caching

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT p.timestamp,
      COUNT(*) as total,
      date_part('hour', p.timestamp) as hour
      FROM parties as p
      WHERE p.timestamp >= TIMESTAMP 'today' AND p.timestamp < TIMESTAMP 'tomorrow'
      AND p.member_id = 1
      GROUP BY p.timestamp, hour;
```

which will grouped how many people by hour:

```
+-------------------------+-------+------+
|        Timestamp        | Total | Hour |
+-------------------------+-------+------+
| 2018-11-21 12:00:00+07  |    10 |   12 |
| 2018-11-21 13:00:00+07  |     2 |   13 |
| 2018-11-21 14:00:00+07  |     2 |   14 |
| 2018-11-21 16:00:00+07  |     1 |   16 |
| 2018-11-21 17:00:00+07  |    21 |   17 |
| 2018-11-21 19:00:00+07  |    18 |   19 |
| 2018-11-21 20:00:00+07  |     8 |   20 |
| 2018-11-21 21:00:00+07  |     1 |   21 |
+-------------------------+-------+------+
```

My question is, if I refetch some API end point that will query above statement, would it be the data in the past hour cached automatically? because in my case, if there is a new data, it will update the last hour's row only.

If not how to cache it? Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you concerned about caching?  How long does it take the query to run?

Comment: @GordonLinoff 2.752 ms in average, what if the data is too large to count in every hour?

Comment: What if new data is inserted into the table? what if the value of `today`changes overnight?

Comment: 2.752 ms is really, really fast.

Comment: PostgreSQL caches data automaticlly based on LRU algorithm (check this link: https://madusudanan.com/blog/understanding-postgres-caching-in-depth/). What you're doing is premature optimization here ;)

Answer (score 5):

PSQL can not cache result of query itself. The solution is cache the result at API application layer.
I prefer using [redis](https://redis.io/) to cache it. Using a `hash` with `fields` is `year+month+day+hour` and `value` is total online user of each hour. Example:

```
 hash: useronline
 field: 2018112112 - value: 10
 field: 2018112113 - value: 2
```

You also set a timeout on key. After the timeout has expired, the key will automatically be deleted. I will set 1 hour in here.

```
EXPIRE useronline 3600
```

When have API request we will get result in redis cache first. If do not exist or expired call query to database layer to get result, save to redis cache again. Reponse result to client.
Here is list of [redis clients](https://redis.io/clients) suitable for programing language.